# Is there a situation in which using `i <= 2` in place of `i < 3` in loops would cause a change in behavior of the loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, increment

This is probably a silly question. I do a lot of data extrapolation with `for` loops in my applications. In almost all cases I tend to find `i <= 2` easier to read/interpret than `i < 3`. Based on what I know they should always mean the same thing, but I'm wondering if there are special cases where they would be evaluated differently when used in a `for` loop. For example, if you used `++i` instead of `i++`.

Comment: if the => or < operators were overloaded for the iterator, the behavior could be different. That is really obscure, though. For an integer however, there is no difference.

Comment: @GáborBakos - `i` is always some form of an int. In most cases it's `Int32`.

Comment: To the downvoters and general people who think this question isn't a good fit for SO, I'm curious, which of the SE network would be the best place to ask something like this? While not necessarily a specific programming problem, I can see the educational value of it (after all, you should learn the important difference of ++i vs i++ somewhere too)

Comment: @cost Yeah, there's nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, however I think a general, *"I was wondering if..."* question is a bad fit.  SO is more about *real* programming problems that were *actually* encountered.  If he wrote, "I observed different behavior, and want to understand the reason why", I'd be more interested.

Comment: For integer-value types and 2 vs 3 it is the same operation, without any difference. For float-value types - not (2.3 > 2 but <3). For custom type - depends on how operators are overloaded. However, if you take not 2 and 3, but n and n+1 - there are difference if n is Int32.MaxValue, hence n+1 = Int32.MaxValue +1 = Int32.MinValue. Also, in C# there is difference in return value of ++i vs i++, but no performance difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided that `i` is an integer, then the expressions `i<=2` and `i<3` should be identical in function.
(they may be slightly different in terms of speed performance)

If `i` has type `float`, `double`, `decimal`, or related, then a value of `2.3` would fail the first test, but pass the second test.

If you specifically overload the `operator<` or `operator<=`, then you could make anything possible.